# ¿Cómo construir método de test unitario usando Mock donde se utilizan varias tablas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, test, mock

Necesito construir un método de Test Unitario donde obtengo una lista (modelo) a partir de varias tablas. ¿Cómo seria el codigo de este [TestMethod]?

Estoy usando Mock para replicar el DbContext/DbSet pero en realidad aun no comprendo totalmente la lógica para utilizar el Mock.

Método en repositorio:

```
public List<ListViewModel> GetListViewModel(Usuario usuario)
{
    var lst = new List<ListViewModel>();
    lst = (from s in db.A_CC_Solicitud
               join e in db.A_Empresa on s.IdEmpresa equals e.IdEmpresa
               join t in db.A_CC_EstadoSolicitud on s.IdEstado equals t.IdEstado
               join p in db.A_Proyecto on s.IdProyecto equals p.IdProyecto into ps
               from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join c in db.A_Contrato on s.IdContrato equals c.IdContrato into cs
               from c in cs.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where s.IdEstado == 1 || s.IdEstado == 2 && e.IdEmpresa == usuario.IdEmpresa
               select new { s, e, p, c, t })
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(x => new ListViewModel
                  {
                      IdSolicitud = x.s.IdSolicitud,
                      IdEmpresa = x.s.IdEmpresa,
                      Empresa = x.e.Empresa,
                      FechaCrea = x.s.FechaCrea.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                      FechaVigencia = x.s.FechaVigencia.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                      IdProyecto = x.s.IdProyecto,
                      Proyecto = x.p != null ? x.p.Titulo : "",
                      IdContrato = x.s.IdContrato,
                      Contrato = x.c != null ? x.c.Nombre : "",
                      IdEstado = x.s.IdEstado,
                      Estado = x.t.Estado,
                      Titulo = x.s.Titulo
                  }).ToList();
 
    return lst;
}
```

MOCK:

```
 public static class DbContextMock
    {
        public static DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T: class
        {
            var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
            var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
            dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));
            return dbSet.Object;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No es útil hacer test unitario en un repositorio. Los repositorios ayudan creando abstracciones para que sea fácil crear test unitarios en la capa de lógica de negocio.

Comment: OK... Como puedo hacer para obtener esa lista usando el mock, por que la nesecito para probar otras cosas

Answer (score 1):

Al usar el repositorio se tiene una ventaja grande: no se necesita hacer mocks del DbContext. Para lo que quieres basta con crear un Fake del repositorio y que el método   `GetListViewModel()` devuelva una lista de objetos sin tener que llamar la base de datos. Para eso se tendría que trabajar con interfaces y no con tipos concretos, agrego ejemplo:

```
// DemoService pertenece a la capa de lógia de negocios 
    // y hace uso del repositorio DemoData
    using System;
    
    public class DemoService{
    
        // se usa una interfaz y no un tipo concreto
        private readonly IDemoData data;
    
        public DemoService(IDemoData data){
                this.data = data;
        }
        public bool DoSomething(){
    
            // se llama al método GetData(), DemoService no sabe
            // si GetData() le está proporcionando datos reales o falsos
            var result = data.GetData();
    
            return false;
        }
    }
            
    public interface IDemoData{
            int GetData();
    }
    
    // implementación de IDemoData que se conecta a una fuente de datos real
    // base de datos, web api etc       
    public class DemoDataReal : IDemoData
    {
        public int GetData()
        {
            return new Random().Next(); // random response from the data repository
        }
    }
    // implementación de IDemoData se usa para pruebas unitarias
    // los valores que devuelve son estáticos
    public class FakeData : IDemoData
    {
        public int GetData()
        {
            return 0; // fake data for unit testing
        }
    }
            
    
    // Test unitario
    public class DemoServiceTest
        {
            private readonly DemoService service;
    
            public DemoServiceTest()
            {
                // se crea una instancia de FakeRepository 
                // y se inicializa DemoService con ese objeto
                var fakeRepository = new FakeData();
                service = new DemoService(fakeRepository);
            }
    
            [Fact]
            public void SiRespuestaEsCeroRetornaFalso()
            {
                var result = service.DoSomething();
    
                Assert.False(result, "result must be false");
            }
        }
```